# Combinatorics Question about combining rows in a table

Tags: combinatorics

I have a table of rows, some rows I want to combine, but not others, for example because the number of cases in adjoining rows is small. If I have separate rows $A,B,C$, I can combine them into $AB,C; A,BC; AC,B$ (two of three rows remaining), and $ABC$, (three rows collapsed into one).

What is the formulae for the total number of distinct combinations for any number of rows?

Second, what is the formuae for the above, but I only combine adjacent rows, thus I don’t want the combination $AC,B$, because $A$ and $C$ are non-adjacent.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggesdt you to explain a little bit what you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better.

Comment: The first half of the question is still a bit unclear.  For your example with three rows: $A,B,C$ are we allowed $CA,B$?  What about $B,AC$?  What about $A,B,C$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for the second part:**

Suppose you have "rows"  $A~B~C~D~E~F~G$.

Imagine for a moment that there is an extra space inbetween that you can mark whether or not you want to "combine" your rows.

$A\circ B\circ C\circ D\circ E\circ F\circ G$

If you want to combine the rows, then shade in the circle.  If you want to leave them separate then leave the circle empty.

For example:
$A\bullet B \circ C\circ D\circ E\bullet F\bullet G$ will yield the result $AB, C, D, EFG$

> How many ways can you choose to shade the circles?

---

If I am interpreting the first half of the question correctly, it is a great deal harder to explain.  As I understand, you have partitioning the rows into different sets, and you have ordered the partitions themselves and ordered the entries within each partition in lexicographic (alphabetical) order.  Hence why you used $AC,B$ but not $B,AC$ and not $CA,B$ (as these all count the same case).

With that being said, it seems you are counting [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and ranging over all possible $k$ (other than $n$?)

As such, the total would be:

$$B_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}$$

Where $\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\} = \frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n$ is the Stirling number of the second kind for $n$ and $k$, i.e. the number of ways of partitioning a set of $n$ labelled objects (your former rows) into $k$ nonempty unlabeled subsets (your new rows which you later arranged alphabetically).

These $B_n$ have a specific name as well, known as [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

(*if you did not want to count $A,B,C$ as an option, i.e. you always combine at least one row, then you would be interested instead in $B_n - 1$*)

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer “Stirling numbers of the second kind” answered my question. Spot on!
My second question is that when practitioners (like me) categorize or aggregate (for example) age years into groups, we would place the years 14,15,16 in one group, and 17,18,19,20 as well, but not 14,47,16 in one group and not 17,63,19,20. Introducing the rule that non-adjacent age years cannot be in one group would solve part of the problem. How many less “Stirling numbers of the second kind” would I get with that rule?

Comment: I found the answer to my question 2, it is: sum {c-1,ki-1} i=1..c

Comment: @daan the answer I was thinking of for the second part is $2^{n-1}$.  Again, if you don't want to include the possibility of not having combined any at all, then subtract one from it.  This is seen from my description of the problem of asking whether or not you put a solid circle inbetween each (either a yes or no for 2 options) and applying multiplication principle.

Comment: Thanks! The outcome of both fomulae is the same.